# Recovering the probability measure from its Cauchy transform

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory

Page 32 in “Lectures on the Combinatorics of Free Probability” by A. Nica, R. Speicher (link: https://rolandspeicher.files.wordpress.com/2020/06/nica-speicher-book.pdf)
They say that when the Cauchy transform happens to have a continuous extension to $\mathbb{C}^+\cup \mathbb{R}$, then the Stieltjes inversion formula is simply telling that the probability measure has density. I don’t understand how to get (2.22) from (2.20).

If the Cauchy transform $G_{\mu}$ has a continuous extension to $G:\mathbb{C}^+\cup \mathbb{R}$, then
$$
\lim_{y\to0^+} G_{\mu}(x+iy)=G(x)
$$
is uniformly convergent?

Comment: I think you want $G$ uniformly continuous and possibly also bounded.